# Why don't outside currents matter?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, magnetic-fields, electric-circuits

I want to ask that, is there any intuitive way one can understand that why $\oint \mathbf B\cdot \mathrm d\mathbf l$ across a closed loop is $0$ when a wire not enclosed by the loop has current flowing through it.

In other words why do external currents don't matter?

Comment: I have removed the second question from your post to make your post on topic here. Posts should only ask one question

Comment: @FakeMod-Inactiveaccount So then either way there was a reason to close. The OP is free to make a new post asking about the second question though.